# Regex para pegar um parêntesis e a string dentro junto

Tags: javascript, html

preciso remover de uma string um parêntesis com o que está dentro, exemplo de que estou tentando extrair esse parêntesis:

"cargo diretor (a)".

motivo: tenho um projeto antigo que tem uma função ajax que carrega um botão, que tem uma função js dentro chamada "definir()", e dentro da função vão alguns parâmetros, que são nome, cargo e etc... justamente quando carrega o cargo com algum "(a)" a função para de executar informando:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

por isso quero usar a função replace do javascript para remover isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça assim:

```js
var str   = 'cargo diretor (a)';
var regex = /\((.*?)\)/;
str = str.replace(regex, '').trim();

alert(str);
```

[EXEMPLO](https://jsfiddle.net/xky51ggg/) no jsfiddle

Para obter somente o cargo (e se antes do cargo estiver sempre "cargo"):

```js
var str   = 'cargo diretor (a)';
var regex = /\((.*?)\)/;
str = str.replace(regex, '').replace('cargo', '').trim();

alert(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Este deve funcionar:

```
preg_match("/\"(.)*\"/",$input_line,$output_array);
```

Comment: Cuidado Daniel, é suposto ser com javascript. Atenção às tags da pergunta